# How Scala transfers a Seq of Pair to a Map?

Tags: scala

I have some value like following:

```
Seq((1, Some("one")), (1, Some("two")), (1, Some("three")), (2, Some("four")), (2, Some("five")), (3, None))
```

what's the best way to convert to:

```
Map(1 -> Seq("one", "two", "three"), 2 -> Seq("four", "five"), 3 -> Seq())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
val map = orig_data.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2))
```

Comment: Might want to put a strict `toList` at the end of that, as `mapValues` sneakily returns a view that'll re-calculate every time you use the val `map`.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to @Shadowlands yet using a for comprehension and extracting and mapping keys and list values from the grouping, like this

```
for ( (k,xss) <- xs.groupBy(_._1) ) yield k -> xss.flatMap(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `fold`:

```
scala> seq.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Seq[String]].withDefaultValue(Nil)) {
     |   case (m, (k, v)) => m.updated(k, m(k)++v)
     | }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[String]] = 
          Map(1 -> List(one, two, three), 2 -> List(four, five), 3 -> List())
```